# Quickly change views in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: list-view, view

I know this may sound nitpicky, but in SP 2007 changing the view on a list was easily accessible since the view dropdown was permanently attached to the list header.

[image]

In 2010, changing the view is located in the ribbon, which is a couple more clicks and a little more difficult to find it hidden in the Ribbon clutter:

[image]

So the question is, is there a way to make the 2010 change-view dropdown more like the 2007 easily-accessible one?

Comment: Edit: there are no view options under the "Browse" tab for any pages in our site collection because someone modified the breadcrumbs on the master page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on Browse and you should see the breadcrumb that shows the path up to and including the current view.  There is a down arrow twistie after the current view name.  Click on that and it will show all of the defined views.

Comment: Nothing shows in "browse" actually. It is likely due to the way our site is configured. Do you know how to get the options to show in there, perhaps from Central Admin?

Comment: If you have customized the page (added a web part), then the list view does not have focus and the list view drop-down breaks.

Comment: Thank you. That explains it. So is there a workaround for a customized page with an additional web part?

Comment: the default XslListViewWebPart for a view needs to be the first web part on the page.  I'm not sure why Microsoft did it that way but it is in the API that way...

Comment: Thanks, but I realized that our problem actually is the customization on our master page. Whomever did the customization killed the dropdown on the last breadcrumb which shows available views.